# Why not just puke up the crystal?

Tags: juuni-taisen

In the first episode, right after all the members of the game are told to swallow their crystal, it's explained that it's really a long-release poison.

Why didn't the members immediately initiate their gag reflex to throw the crystals up?

I mean, by that point in the anime, there's no way to know if the announcer would or could follow through with his promise of an antidote.

Comment: They are warriors that have been in this game before. except a few new comers. they know how this woks and they don't want to risk their crystal getting stolen. and maybe if they do that they'll lose. nothing has been said about it but maybe they think it was implied?!!

Comment: How had anyone but the previous winner been in the game before?  I thought the point was to kill their opponents.

Comment: I don't know but they mentioned ox and monkey being in the game before I think dog was too